# Is there a reliable website about cosmetic science?

Tags: research, home-remedies, scientific-method, cosmetics

When I read something on nih.gov or nhs.uk, I trust that what I'm reading is scientifically reliable.

However, these sites do not really focus on cosmetics.

I'm looking for a website that is aimed at the general public, and provides information about cosmetics, and various cosmetic procedures like lasering or derma-rolling.

Most of the things I find about cosmetics online are written by questionable sources, such as consumers (who don't have a scientific background), or companies who clearly have a vested interest in certain products.

**Is there an impartial, scientifically reliable and extensive website about cosmetics, cosmetic surgery, cosmetic products, etc?**

Comment: Checkout https://www.beautypedia.com. This features reviews (based on credible research) of make up and skin care products.

Answer (score 4):

I would trust the professional organizations' websites and journals:

- American Academy of Dermatology  http://www.AAD.org
- American Osteopathic College of Dermatology http://www.aocd.org/
- American Journal of Clinical Dermatology https://link.springer.com/journal/40257
- Journal of the American Academy of Dermatology http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/01909622?sdc=1

Or google your terms followed by site:aad.org  or site:aocd.org etc

Finding evidence for the newest procedures is harder; there's simply less of it.  I find this to be the case myself.  Dermatologists themselves differ in what they accept and practice from newer technologies.

Any other major peer reviewed medical reference, like UpToDate, I would as well.